# Unable to read JSON in hive having escape character

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have JSON STRING like this

```
{\"feedback\":{\"timeepoch\":1234355116561,\"meta\":{\"zip\":\"201005\",\"details\":\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"12\\\"}\"}}}
```

When i create hive table on top of the location

```
create table myschema.testtable (payload struct<meta:map<string,string>,timeepoch:bigint>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'                                                                         
 STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'  LOCATION
 '/location/to/file/'
```

i am getting below error on running select query

```
Error: java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start of Object expected (state=,code=0)
```

But if my data come without escape character same thing works.

```
{"feedback":{"timeepoch":1234355116561,"meta\:{"zip":"201005","details":"{\"id\":\"12\"}"}}}
```

How can i use read the json having escape character and in data i don't want to have escape character in column values

Comment: JSONSerDe will work with only valid JSON without slashes. if you can not remove slashes before loading files, then the only option is to create table as STORED as TEXTFILE with single column, then remove extra slashes and parse json using json_tuple or get_json_object

Comment: I tried that as well but its giving diff schema error ```Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different. cannot convert column 0 to struct```